# OAuth 2 Authorization Code Flow vs Implicit Flow in SPA apps

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-page-application

Almost every oauth 2 doc says that the best option to set up authentication is to use the implicit flow, in case you have a spa app, `cause you can't keep a "client secret" secure on the client side as it runs entirely in a browser, except one article, that I was able to find - https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/single-page-apps/#authorization relating to the option of using code flow to imlicit one.

But what If one uses code flow with no client secret stored on the client side with the neccesary use of the "state" parameter and a pre-registered redirect URL on the server side, as there is no way to verify the identity of the client without the "client secret", as it is described in the link above. Maybe I'm missing something, but just wanna know If such an approach  is more secure to use than the implicit flow, that bypasses the code exchange step, or not. Will be glad to hear any suggestions concerning the matter!